# Primary navigation menu & footer not showing in category / tag page

Tags: theme-development, menus, navigation

I tried to find a solution for primary navigation not showing in some pages, ie. archive.php.

I found one [from here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-nav-menu-dissapears-in-category-pages-1?replies=21%29?) but it's still giving me notices.

I'm using `Reverie Theme` in `WordPress 3.6-alpha-23288`

This is my code after implementing the fix

**Plugins/MyMainPlugin.php**

```
add_filter( 'getMainMenu',  array( $this, 'getMainMenu'),           10, 1);
function getMainMenu( $menuLocation ) {
    $locations          = get_nav_menu_locations();

    if ( empty( $menuLocation ) ) {
        $menuLocation   = 'primary_navigation';
    }

    $menuItems          = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $locations[ $menuLocation ] );
    if ( empty( $menuItems ) ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location'    => $menuLocation,
            'container'         => false,
            'menu_class'        => '',
            'echo'              => true,
            'before'            => '',
            'after'             => '',
            'link_before'       => '',
            'link_after'        => '',
            'depth'             => 0,
            'items_wrap'        => '<ul class="nav-bar">%3$s</ul>',
            'walker'            => new reverie_walker() ) );
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Theme/header.php**

```
if ( !apply_filters( 'getMainMenu', 'primary_navigation' ) ) {
    $backup     = $wp_query;
    $wp_query   = NULL;
    $wp_query   = new WP_Query( array( 'post-type' => 'post' ) );
    apply_filters( 'getMainMenu', 'primary_navigation' );
    $wp_query   = $backup;
}
```

**Notices**

> Notice: is_category was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do
>   not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return
>   false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This
>   message was added in version 3.1.) in
>   /var/www/customers/xxx/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php
>   on line 2981 Notice: is_tag was called incorrectly. Conditional query
>   tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always
>   return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information.
>   (This message was added in version 3.1.) in
>   /var/www/customers/xxx/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php
>   on line 2981

Any ideas how to solve this, and might be causing this? I have no idea what's causing that.

**Update**
This actually affects to footer as well. So, I don't see any footer on my archive.php page either.

Comment: It says `Notice: is_category was called incorrectly` but I don't see `is_category` in your code. Please supply, probably, `archive.php` essential part.

Comment: @MaxYudin my archive.php doesn't actually matter, because it show the notice even when `archive.php` includes only `<?php get_header(); get_footer(); ?>` – the notice is caused by the header.php code found above in my question

Answer (score 1):

This line looks strange:

```
$wp_query   = new WP_Query( array( 'post-type' => 'post','page' ) );
```

you should try instead:

```
$wp_query   = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => array('post','page') ) );
```

**ps:** thanks to @Johannes Pille for the `post_type` correction.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you input... but that doesn't make any difference.

Comment: In addition, the `post_type` parameter is with an underscore, not a hyphen.

Comment: thanks @Johannes Pille, not sure how I missed it ;-)